# Entity Framework: Select all entities whose sub entities have a certain flag set

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

This should be an easy to answer question, though I can't really figure it out.
Here is the situation:

I use entity framework 4.1 as ORM using Code First. I have defined a pretty complex object model and everything works well so far.

Part of my model looks like this (left unimportant parts out for sakes of clarity):

```
public class Tier1
{
public virtual ICollection<Tier2> t2 {get; set;}
}

public Class Tier2
{
public virtual Tier3 t3 {get; set;}
}

public Class Tier3
{
public bool isActive
}
```

How can I formulate my statement in order to retrieve `tier1` elements including only `tier3` entities that have `isActive` set to `true`?

```
context.Tier1s.Where(???)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming tier2 has only one tier3 yeah? It seems that way in your code. If so try this:

```
var myTiers = context.Tier1s
    .Where(tier => tier.t2.Any(tier2 => tier2.t3.isActive))
    .ToList();
```